# Where do I put my package contents?

Tags: python

I have created a Python package... with nothing in it. All it is, is the simple structure from the [Python packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

```
/example_pkg
  /example_pkg
    __init__.py
  setup.py
  LICENSE
  README.md
```

Where do you put the files you want to create? In the root folder or somewhere else?

Comment: I think the user guide makes a mistake calling that top directory `/example_pkg`. In fact, the code should live in a repository somewhere (git, mercurial, etc) and multiple copies can be checked out at the same time. You may have `/joes_foo`, `/foo_with_fixes` and `foo_for_bug_666` all in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files should be under example_pkg which has the `__init__` in the example.
Each folder that represents a package or sub-package should have a `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

In the Python ecosystem, there's (at least) two related, but different things called "package":

- [prefixes in "dotted module names"](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages), usually represented by directories containing a `__init__.py` file
- named units of code distribution (e.g. via PyPI), installable with `pip` and related tools

Following the instructions you've linked, you've probably created a structure for the latter (a directory containing `setup.py` etc.) containing one package of the first type (the inner `example_pkg` directory.)

```
example_pkg/
├── example_pkg/
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

Usually, you should put your library's code into the package of the first type (the inner `example_pkg` folder), so that it is properly contained by that namespace.

```
example_pkg/
├── example_pkg/
│   ├── __init__.py <--- put your code here
|   ├── a_sub_pkg/
│   │   ├── __init__.py  <-- or maybe here
│   │   └── something.py <-- or here
│   └── another_thing.py <-- or here
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start by simply putting all your source code files in the root directory. It might be a good idea though to put different files (eg. images) in a dedicated folder.

When your project becomes larger it may be a good idea to create more subfolders ("packages") but this *really* depends on your case. From The Zen of Python follows that you should keep your package structure simple.

`>>> import this`

> The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
>
> **Beautiful is better than ugly.**
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   **Simple is better than complex.**
>   Complex is better than complicated.
>   **Flat is better than nested.**
>   Sparse is better than dense.
>   **Readability counts.**
>   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.
>   Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
>   Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
>   If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
>   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

*(**emphasis** added)*

So basically it is up to you but you should keep these this in mind.

Comment: What about that last part "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"?

Comment: If they aid in making code more readable (especially when a project becomes larger/more complex) they are fine to use. But it really depends on how big the project gets. It would be overly complicated for a small project to use many namespaces but then again they can be beneficial for a larger project. In my humble opinion the poem highlights the KISS principle much more than the concept of namespaces. I acknowledge that your answer shows indeed how most libraries organize their files. But I thought maybe the OP was looking for more general, "pythonic" advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your package up into sub-packages and modules in whatever way makes sense to you (using new files for modules and directories for packages). I would start by looking at the structure of some of the popular Python packages in order to get well rounded view of what the best practices are.

Take a look through some of the below packages to get a feel for what's possible and what is considered best practise. Pay particular attention to the `setup.py` and `__init__.py` files and the directory structure of the project as a whole.

- [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests)
- [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter)
- [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask)
- [scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy)